# Truffle test throws an error in "before each" hook

Tags: truffle-test, flash-loans

Developing a flash loan which i use truffle to test my code,

```
david@LAPTOP-3KIH2P0K:/mnt/c/pr0/flash/FlashloanLeveragedYieldFarm$ truffle test
Using network 'development'.


Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.



  Contract: FlashLoanTemplate
    Performing Flash Loan...
      1) "before each" hook for "Borrowing 1M DAI and throws revert info msg."

  Contract: LeveragedYieldFarm
    Uniswap
      2) "before each" hook for "swapping 1 ETH for DAI..."


  0 passing (4s)
  2 failing

  1) Contract: FlashLoanTemplate
       "before each" hook for "Borrowing 1M DAI and throws revert info msg.":
     Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? You might also see this error if you are not using the correct ABI for the contract you are retrieving data from, requesting data from a block number that does not exist, or querying a node which is not fully synced.
      at ABICoder.decodeParametersWith (/home/david/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/index.js:297:1)
      at ABICoder.decodeParameters (/home/david/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/index.js:284:1)
      at Contract._decodeMethodReturn (/home/david/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-eth/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/index.js:469:1)
      at Method.outputFormatter (/home/david/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-eth/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/index.js:759:1)
      at Method.formatOutput (/home/david/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-eth/node_modules/web3-core-method/lib/index.js:146:1)
      at sendTxCallback (/home/david/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-eth/node_modules/web3-core-method/lib/index.js:522:1)
      at /home/david/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js:307:1
      at /home/david/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/provider/wrapper.js:107:1
      at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/home/david/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3/node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js:98:1)
      at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/home/david/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:1)
      at XMLHttpRequest.exports.modules.996763.XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/home/david/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:208:1)
      at XMLHttpRequest.exports.modules.996763.XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/home/david/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:318:1)
      at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/david/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:289:47)
      at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)

  2) Contract: LeveragedYieldFarm
       "before each" hook for "swapping 1 ETH for DAI...":
     Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? You might also see this error if you are not using the correct ABI for the contract you are retrieving data from, requesting data from a block number that does not exist, or querying a node which is not fully synced.
      at ABICoder.decodeParametersWith (/home/david/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/index.js:297:1)
      at ABICoder.decodeParameters (/home/david/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/index.js:284:1)
      at Contract._decodeMethodReturn (/home/david/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-eth/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/index.js:469:1)
      at Method.outputFormatter (/home/david/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-eth/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/index.js:759:1)
      at Method.formatOutput (/home/david/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-eth/node_modules/web3-core-method/lib/index.js:146:1)
      at sendTxCallback (/home/david/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-eth/node_modules/web3-core-method/lib/index.js:522:1)
      at /home/david/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js:307:1
      at /home/david/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/provider/wrapper.js:107:1
      at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/home/david/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3/node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js:98:1)
      at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/home/david/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:1)
      at XMLHttpRequest.exports.modules.996763.XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/home/david/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:208:1)
      at XMLHttpRequest.exports.modules.996763.XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/home/david/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:318:1)
      at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/david/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:289:47)
      at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Comment: Usually a problem with the "before hook" is in the migrations scripts. Can you share them?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.